# Using expansion in toggleocgs argument

Tags: expansion, ocg, ocg-p

I want to use `ocg-p` to define an environment `step` which has an Optional Content Group (OCG / "layer") with a "+" character in the margin that allows you to toggle the group.

I use `\stepi` to give each layer a unique name.

However, `\toggleocgs` does not seem to expand its argument `{step\stepi}`, so the below does not work (clicking on the "+" margin note does not do anything). With the `ocgx` package and `\switchocgs` instead of `ocg-p`'s `\toggleocgs` it does work, but I need `ocg-p` for XeLaTeX support.

I'm guessing I need some `\expandafter` magic to make sure that `{step\stepi}` is expanded *before* `\toggleocgs`, but have no clue how to use that macro, even after reading several Q&As here.

How do I fix the below so that "+" correctly toggles the layer?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocg-p}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

\newcommand\stepi{1}
\newenvironment{step}
    {\marginnote{\toggleocgs{step\stepi}{+}}
        \begin{ocg}{Step \stepi}{step\stepi}{0}}
    {\end{ocg}
        \xdef\stepi{\the\numexpr\stepi+1\relax}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{step}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{step}

\end{document}
```

The code responsible for parsing the argument of `\toggleocgs` is the following:

```tex
\def\@ocgp@parseSpaceSeperatedList#1{\@ocgp@doparseSpaceSeperatedList#1 \relax}
\def\@ocgp@doparseSpaceSeperatedList#1 #2{%
  \ifcsname OCGpdfobj#1\endcsname%
    \xdef\@ocgp@ocgobjlist{\@ocgp@ocgobjlist\space\csname OCGpdfobj#1\endcsname}%
  \fi
  \ifx#2\relax
    %\@ocgp@ocgobjlist % only for debugging reasons
  \else
    \expandafter\@ocgp@doparseSpaceSeperatedList
  \fi
  #2%
}
```

The version in `ocgx`'s `\switchocgs` is slightly different:

```tex
\csname ocgx@end:ENDOFOCGS\endcsname
\def\ocgx@listOCG#1 {%
  \unless\ifcsname ocgx@end:#1\endcsname
    \ifcsname OCGpdfobj#1\endcsname
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\ocgx@list\expandafter{%
        \ocgx@list
        \csname OCGpdfobj#1\endcsname\space}%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\ocgx@listOCG
  \fi
}
```

But I don't really understand what's going on here.

Comment: Just replace `\usepackage{ocg-p}` with  `\usepackage{ocgx2}`.

Comment: @AlexG I hadn't seen that, thank you!

Comment: You may need to delete the `aux` file first before running `xelatex` on the modified input.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, it's working now, thank you. I just hadn't seen that there was a new package. Do you want to write an answer for this? I cannot really imagine others coming with the exact same problem, but you never know whom it may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `ocg-p` has become a bit old. Package `ocgx2` can be used as a replacement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

\newcommand\stepi{1}
\newenvironment{step}
    %{\marginnote{\toggleocgs{step\stepi}{+}} % also works as ocg-p commands are supported
    {\marginnote{\switchocg{step\stepi}{+}}
        \begin{ocg}{Step \stepi}{step\stepi}{0}}
    {\end{ocg}
        \xdef\stepi{\the\numexpr\stepi+1\relax}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{step}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{step}

\end{document}
```

Note that if `hyperref` is loaded, layer-switching links by `ocgx2` are styled according to the `hyperref` settings for internal links (`linkbordercolor`, `linkcolor`, `pdfborder`, `pdfborderstyle`). In order to locally suppress styling (but keeping links functional), `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` can be used as in `\marginnote{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\switchocg{step\stepi}{+}}`.

---

Here is an enhanced version, where "**-**" replaces "**+**" in the margin when the layer becomes visible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ocgx2}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

\newcommand\stepi{1}
\newenvironment{step}{%
  \marginnote{%
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
    \switchocg{step\stepi}{%
      \begin{ocmd}{\Not{step\stepi}}\makebox[0pt][l]{$+$}\end{ocmd}%
      \begin{ocmd}{\AnyOn{step\stepi}}$-$\end{ocmd}%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{ocg}{Step \stepi}{step\stepi}{off}%
}{%
  \end{ocg}%
  \xdef\stepi{\the\numexpr\stepi+1\relax}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{step}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{step}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the extension looks great, too :) I had something similar, but more hacky. I'm using `\large $\circ$` for `-` and `\large $\bullet$` for `+` which also looks nice.

Comment: I used the `ocmd`-kind of layer to achieve the toggling of the link text. Yes, there are other symbols thinkable to be used as link text. The `fontawesome` package has maybe a few.